# VACUUM ANALYSE not reducing index bloat, only VACUUM FULL

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

We are experiencing many slowdowns due to index bloat. On trying to optimize the index, recreating it seems to generate a much smaller index:

`reviews_hotel_id_connection_id_review_date_created_at_review_id`: original index
`reviews_hotel_id_connection_id_review_date_created_at_new`: exact duplicate of the original index, recreated

```
 reviews | reviews_hotel_id_connection_id_review_date_created_at_review_id | 5296 kB  
 reviews | reviews_hotel_id_connection_id_review_date_created_at_new       | 2944 kB
```

The new index is only 55% the size of the original index!

Running `VACUUM ANALYSE reviews` doesn't result in any index reduction!

Running `VACUUM FULL reviews` makes the original index have exactly the same size as the new index:

```
 reviews | reviews_hotel_id_connection_id_review_date_created_at_new       | 2944 kB 
 reviews | reviews_hotel_id_connection_id_review_date_created_at_review_id | 2944 kB
```

Although `VACUUM FULL` locks the table even for reads! Is are an option for optimizing indexes without causing downtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VACUUM` typically does not shrink the tables or indexes.

From v12 on, you can use `REINDEX CONCURRENTLY` for that.

Before, you would create a second index with `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`, then drop the old index. But that wouldn't work for a constraint index.

But 50% bloat like in this case is quite normal and healthy for a b-tree index, and I wouldn't worry about it.